# Displaying images is not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After `uploading images`, what I want is I want to display that `image`. It is working properly when the image is of `.jpg` extension. But when I upload `pdf` files its gets uploaded but it is not displaying the file.

**JQUERY**

```
function setImagesSitePlot(JsonObject) {
for (i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
    var obj = JsonObject[i].Filename;
    var obj2 = "ImgSitePlotManual";
    var obj3 = JsonObject[i].FileType;
    var dataImageName = JsonObject[i].ImageName;

    var ImgObj = parent.document.getElementById(obj2);
    ImgObj.src = SharedFilePath + obj;
    $(ImgObj).attr("data-imagename", dataImageName);
}
```

}

**HTML**

```
<img width="500" class="img-responsive" id="ImgSitePlotManual" data-imagename="" style="width: 606px;" />
```

Comment: Is that possible. I mean how an image tag can show preview of a pdf file?

Comment: @KiranDash: Yeah, i know. So what should I do in order to make display for both the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to use an image representing the pdf file icon that you return in your JSON string once the uploaded file is `pdf`.

Or you can display the pdf file in an `object` element:

```
<object data='http://website.com/nameoffolder/documentname.pdf#toolbar=1' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='700px' id='PdfSitePlotManual'>
```

You cannot view pdf in an image.

Make use of the `fileType` property you are already returning:

```
for (i = 0; i < JsonObject.length; i++) {
    var obj = JsonObject[i].Filename;
    var obj3 = JsonObject[i].FileType;
    var dataImageName = JsonObject[i].ImageName;

    if(obj3 == 'img')
    {
       var ImgObj = parent.document.getElementById("ImgSitePlotManual");
       ImgObj.src = SharedFilePath + obj;
       $(ImgObj).attr("data-imagename", dataImageName);
    }

    else if(obj3 == 'pdf')
    {
       var PdfObj = parent.document.getElementById("PdfSitePlotManual");
       PdfObj.setAttribute('data', SharedFilePath + obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks KAD, but what if i want to display anything based on the users choice. what tag should I use than

Comment: when you upload the file, you can identify the extension and mimetype, then based on this you return the json response.. that would be by choice

Comment: yes, can u show it how should I do that. if u want i will post the json too

Comment: just return an extra property in the array within the json response per each file in order to identify its type.. Based on this property you then either set the `img` source or the `object` data attributes with the proper url

Comment: i m still confused how to return which extra property. it would be great if u help me out. also do let me know if u need anything from my side

Comment: i am getting `dataImageName` as `I-GJ-SURT-ENB-0479_C3//SitePlot//I-BR-BRRJ-ENB-9004_C2.pdf` in `jsonobject`

Comment: hey KAD, kindly help. I need to give it today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151569/discussion-between-vvvv-and-kad).

Comment: hey KAD, can u come on chat. a small doubt I have which we can resolve and finish it off